# Sklearn GridSearchCV Delay

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am using this code to do a grid search

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(gbm, param_grid, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=-1, cv=predefined_split, verbose=2)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(df[features], df[target])

# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
sys.stdout.flush()
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

But the output I see is

```
Start time GBM  2018-08-03 20:16:35.647916
{'n_estimators': [20, 40, 80]}
Fitting 1 folds for each of 3 candidates, totalling 3 fits
[CV] n_estimators=20 .................................................
[CV] n_estimators=40 .................................................
[CV] n_estimators=80 .................................................
[CV] .................................. n_estimators=20, total= 1.9min
[CV] .................................. n_estimators=40, total= 2.3min
[CV] .................................. n_estimators=80, total= 3.3min

[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   3 out of   3 | elapsed:  3.5min finished
```

So the execution finishes, but I see large delays until it actually prints the results of the execution. I.e. the output freezes there, saying Done, but then it takes a while until I see my desired results. Why is this happening, and how can I see my output faster, so I don't waste time waiting?

The train data is really large, about 2GB.

So how can I flush the output faster?